# Remove Virtual Directory name from the Website URl

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a asp.net mvc website hosted on godaddy shared server. I want to write a url rewrite rule which would remove the virtual directory name.

Below are few my website URLs. All URLs works. but I want to redirect any url that has virtual directory name (breederyellowpages) in it to the root.

http://www.breederyellowpages.com

http://www.breederyellowpages.com/breederyellowpages

http://www.breederyellowpages.com/breederyellowpages/blog/other/introducing-suggest-a-feature-in-account-management

I tried to research & implement couple of ways of doing that. but its either not working or I am doing it wrong.

https://weblogs.asp.net/jhallal/remove-hosting-folder-name-from-mvc-url

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a try:

```
<rule name="RemoveVirtualDirectory">
                <match url="breederyellowpages/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.breederyellowpages.com$" />
                </conditions>
</rule>
```

Comment: I updated web.config but not working. it still redirects to .com/breederyellowpages

Comment: Can you try updating to `<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />`

Comment: Hm weird. Try `<action type="Redirect" url="/" appendQueryString="false" />` instead of `<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />`

Comment: I have an additional rule, is it making it to redirect to /breederyellowpages 

`<rule name="Force WWW">
          <match url="^(.*)$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www\.)(.*)$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{C:0}{PATH_INFO}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>`

Comment: Try commenting out that rule

Comment: After commenting out, I guess it do not redirect to /breederyellowpages automatically when user keys in only till .com But, I still what that rule to force to use www in url